# How to create javaFX programs in JDK 13

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I use JavaFX since JDK 8 for developing desktop applications with awesome UI components. Recently I downloaded the JDK version 13 to my intellij IDEA and started to develop a small program through the Scene Builder application. I set the path for scene builder first and created a JavaFX project, but It does not work. when I press the play button, following errors are shown

```
Error:(21, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method launch(java.lang.String[])
  location: class sample.Main
Error:(15, 35) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Scene
  location: class sample.Main
Error:(13, 39) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getClass()
  location: class sample.Main
Error:(13, 23) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable FXMLLoader
  location: class sample.Main
Error:(13, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Parent
  location: class sample.Main
Error:(11, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(12, 23) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Stage
  location: class sample.Main
Error:(6, 20) java: package javafx.scene does not exist
Error:(9, 27) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Application
Error:(7, 20) java: package javafx.stage does not exist
Error:(5, 20) java: package javafx.scene does not exist
Error:(3, 26) java: package javafx.application does not exist
Error:(4, 19) java: package javafx.fxml does not exist
```

why this is happens,
what should i do for get rid of these errors, and to develop application as before in JDK 8,
is there a replacement for JavaFX to create UI based applications.

Comment: [JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/) was removed from the JDK in Java 11. You now have to add it to your project as a library/dependency. Check out the [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) guide.

Comment: @Slaw Yeah now it works.